# Why isn't backdrop-filter: blur() working properly?

Tags: html, css, blur

I'm trying to implement this image:

[image]

Where, a div with text "Dog" is partially covering and **blurring** the image. So I tried this:

```css
   .profile {
      background-image: url(https://townofbeekmantown.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/2-dog.jpg);
      width: 250px;
      height: 250px;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: 0px;
    }

    .name {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      width: 100%;
      opacity: 60%;
      backdrop-filter: blur(10px); // should do the trick but not working??
    }
```

```html
<body class="profile">
    <div class="name">Dog</div>
</body>
```

[image]

As you can see, although the div has the right color/opacity, it is not **blurring** the part of the image it covers.

If backdrop-filter is applied on `<div class="name"></div>`, then shouldn't it take affect on the element behind it (which is `<body class="profile">`)? I'm confused as to what I am doing wrong. If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: the `<body>` element is the root of the visible document and is a child of the root `<html>` element. So you cannot have `<div><body></body></div>`.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74085350/backdrop-filter-doesnt-apply-if-parents-opacity-is-less-than-1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me:

- Change `<body class="profile">` to something like `<div class="profile">`.

  - `<body>` is a *special* HTML element.
- Remove `opacity: 0.6`. It makes the entire element translucent which isn't what you want.
- Instead, change the `background-color` to `rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.6 )` - then the `backdrop` will be partially visible through this semitransparent background.
- Also, I replaced `width: 100%` with `right: 0;` as `width: 100%` will be affected by `box-sizing:` which will trip you up as you work on the textual content of your HTML.
- You also need to add `position: relative;` to `.profile` so that the `.name`'s `position: absolute` works.

```css
.profile {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;

    background-image: url("https://townofbeekmantown.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/2-dog.jpg");
   
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 0px;
}

.name {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;

    background: rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0.6 );
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);

    color: white;

    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="profile">
        <div class="name">Dog</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The bit that enlightened me was that blur does NOT work with an element's opacity (via css opacity prop) but with the alpha layer of its background. So opacity 1 and background color with rgba is what works. Opacity < 1 and solid background color doesn't work. Thank you for that!

Answer (score 2):

You could set a transparent background using `RGBA` instead of using `opacity` to have the blur effect on the background. Also note that you are using an invalid order of HTML code.

The order is as follow:

```html
<html>
<head>
<!-- All meta tags -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- All your elements such as divs, navs etc.. -->
</body>
</html>
```

So if we take your code, you would have something like this:

```css
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
```

`!` For the sake of demonstration, I added `position: relative` to the profile class, this ensures your `name` element stays inside of the box. Remove that line if you are planning to copy the code below or don't want to have this.

```css
.profile {
  background: url(https://townofbeekmantown.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/2-dog.jpg);
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
.name {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
  color: white;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px); // should do the trick but not working??
}
```

```html
 <div class="profile">
  <div class="name">Dog</div>
</div>
```