# background-filter (blur) doesn't blur the background

Tags: html, css

I can't manage to make `backdrop-filter (blur)` work for some reasons...

I've already tried looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997948/backdrop-filter-not-working-for-nested-elements-in-chrome#) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73988128/why-isnt-backdrop-filter-blur-working-properly) already asked, but couldn't figure it out and implement it in my case. I've also tried not nesting my items and just place them one above the other using `position: absolute` but it gives exactly the same result.

If that can help I'm working on a React 18.2 + Tailwind 3.2 environment and tried to show you my issue using plain HTML / JS.

Here's a simplified version of my code :

```css
#result {
  /* Using a background image, but any image would do the job */
  background-image: url("https://www.radiofrance.fr/s3/cruiser-production/2022/06/5f6ac5ab-37d9-4ca6-8f79-3694fcfec071/560x315_paysage-monet.webp");
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 0;
}

#filter {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.3;
  backdrop-filter: blur(6px);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="result">
  <div id="filter"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to change `id's` of `div's`... First `div` must be `filter` and second one must be `result`... or just replace each other in `css`. btw. no need for `z-index` in `css`

Comment: *Because it applies to everything behind the element, to see the effect you must make the element or its background at least partially transparent.* source: [MDN - backdrop-filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter), you could change the background to: `rgba(0,0,255,0.3)` and remove the `opacity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your background-color with alpha value if you want to have a background with less opacity.
When you apply `opacity`, it'll be applied to the whole element. So you need to remove the `opacity` and change your background-color as below:

```css
#result {
  /* Using a background image, but any image would do the job */
  background-image: url("https://www.radiofrance.fr/s3/cruiser-production/2022/06/5f6ac5ab-37d9-4ca6-8f79-3694fcfec071/560x315_paysage-monet.webp");
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

#filter {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
  backdrop-filter: blur(6px);
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;

}
```

```html
<div id="result">
  <div id="filter"></div>
</div>
```