# Blur Behind Bootstrap Tooltip

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, opacity, gaussianblur

### ***What I want:***

The area behind a tooltip is blurred:

[image: The ideal version of what I want. The text behind the tooltip is blurred.]

---

### ***What I have***

The area behind the tooltip is not blurred:

[image: Nothing seems to work, and I always have this where the text behind the tooltip is not affected]

---

### ***My Code***

Please see my jsFiddle for the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/heetertc/d8qw03jg/33/.

Below is just the essentials to show what I've tried:

```
/* CSS */
.tooltip-inner{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
.tooltip-inner::before{
  content: ''
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
.tooltip-inner::after{
  content: ''
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}
.card{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}
.card::before{
  content: ''
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}
```

```
<!-- HTML -->
<button 
  class='btn btn-primary' 
  data-bs-html = 'true' 
  data-bs-toggle  = 'tooltip'
  data-bs-title = '
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-text">
        <div class="card-header">OK</div>
        <div class="card-body">OKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKO</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  '
>
  Neque porro quisquam est
</button>
```

---

### ***What I've tried***

Here are the things I've tried:

- [Why isn't backdrop-filter: blur() working properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73988128/1152809)

  - Says to use `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3)`
- https://www.reddit.com/r/css/comments/14r41xo/how_do_you_achieve_this_blur_effect/

  - Says to use `backdrop-filter:blur(3px);`
  - Also mentions using a pseudo-element, ie `:before`

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
  const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl).show())
})
```

```css
.tooltip-inner {
  padding: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.tooltip-inner:before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

.card {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: 20px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}

#blur {
  filter: blur(0px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Wrapper container -->
<div class="container py-4">

  <div id="blur">
    The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
    ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
    Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
    architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
    <button class='btn btn-primary' data-bs-html='true' data-bs-toggle='tooltip' data-bs-title='
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-text">
          <div class="card-header">OK</div>
          <div class="card-body">OKOKOKOKOKOKOKOKO</div>
        </div>
      </div>'>
      Neque porro quisquam est
    </button> , qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam
    corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" 1914 translation
    by H. Rackham "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder
    of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves
    or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical
    exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?" Section 1.10.33 of
    "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate
    non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo
    minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae.
    Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat."
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backdrop filter doesn't apply if parent's opacity is less than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74085350/backdrop-filter-doesnt-apply-if-parents-opacity-is-less-than-1)

Comment: Force `.tooltop` opacity to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View the generated source and you will see what is going on.

Your `.card` is rendered inside of `.tooltip-inner` which is within `.tooltip` so your blur rule should be on `.tooltip` not `.card`. Additionally `backdrop-filter: blur()` does not work well when applied to an element that is not fully opaque. In your case the following rules will make content covered by the tooltip blurred:

```
.tooltip.show {
    opacity: 1;
    backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/moob/1kbLfuch/

Comment: @Yogi Try with and without and you'll see the difference. With 0.9 opacity the text is half blurred in Chrome - almost like there's solid text on top of blurred text. Increase the blur to some big number and it's even more apparent.